# Rails How to access "params" inside a module method that it's inside a helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to access `params` inside a method that it's in a module that it'is inside a module help. For example.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  module ExampleModule
    extend self

    def an_example_method
      //access params here
    end
  end
end
```

How to do that?

Comment: If you are using it as a singleton you would need to pass the params into the  method. A better question is why you are trying to do this in the first place.

Comment: I don't is using as a singleton. I want that to use the method as fully-qualified name in controller, like that "ExampleModule.an_example_method".

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the simplest thing to do would be to pass the params like this

module ApplicationHelper
  module ExampleModule
    extend self

```
def an_example_method(params)
  params.each do |param|
    puts param
  end
  //access params here
end
```

end
end

now form your coltroller you can call the an_example_method mthod like this

```
ExampleModule.an_example_method(params)
```

I hope that this helps